# How to catch the event in cycle angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

Im learning angular 2. I have array of strings (1 symbol in cell). im cheking this array in cycle, and when any symbol in array == "," i must stop the code and wait for user's input (like prompt, but i need same using ). When user press "enter" it should resume with this value. What is the best way to catch event?

```html
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'code_input',
    template: `<div class="form-group">
    <h4>Input</h4>
    <input type="text">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="comment" (keyup)="outcode(inputCode)"
              [(ngModel)]="inputCode"></textarea>
    <h4>Output</h4>
    <div>{{ outputCode }}</div>
                </div>`,
    styles: [`
        :host {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    
}
    `],
    styleUrls: ['bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css', 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css']
})
export class CodeInput {
    @Input() inputCode: string;
    outputCode: string;



    outcode(inputCode: string) {

        var acc: string[];
        acc = inputCode.split('');
        var cpu = new Array(30000).fill(0);

        var brc: number = 0;

        var j: number = 0;
        this.outputCode = "";

        for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            if(acc[i] === ',') {  

        //wait for input here, after input cpu[j] = (user's symbol)
                 
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain what is the goal of this and whether the array is coming from user input too or not? @Vadim

Comment: the goal of this - interpriter of simple language. array is coming from textarea from user input, yes

Answer (score 0):

Try event emmiter binding.

```
@Output() enter = new EventEmitter();
```

then inside method,

```
outcode(inputCode: string) {

    var acc: string[];
    acc = inputCode.split('');
    var cpu = new Array(30000).fill(0);

    var brc: number = 0;

    var j: number = 0;
    this.outputCode = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        if(acc[i] === ',') {  


             this.enter.emit({event:$event});

        }
    }
}
```

And in HTML add enter method like below

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="comment" (keyup)="outcode(inputCode)" (enter)="userEntered()"
 [(ngModel)]="inputCode"></textarea>
```

So you can write your code in userEntered() method.

Comment: i need something like a "prompt" in js, but in input before textarea.
            if(acc[i] === ',') {
               cpu[j] = prompt("variable","");
            }
thats works fine, but i need same in input, not in prompt(